# Unit test failing when directive is an Attribute

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-jasmine, angular-directive

I have a directive which is declared as an Attribute:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            data: "="
        },
        template:
            '<p class="my-paragrapgh">' +
                '<label>Hello</label>' +
            '</p>'
    }
});
```

I have a unit test, which is failing:

```
describe('myDirective test', function () {
var scope, compile, element;

beforeEach(module('myModule'));

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    element = angular.element("<div my-directive></div>");
    $compile(element);
    scope.$digest();
}));

it('should have a my-paragrapgh class', function () {
    expect($(element).find('p')[0]).toHaveClass('my-paragrapgh');
});

});
```

However, if i convert my diretive to an Element, and remove replace and transclude:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //replace: true,
        //transclude: true,
        scope: {
            data: "="
        },
        template:
            '<p class="my-paragrapgh">' +
                '<label>Hello</label>' +
            '</p>'
    }
});
```

My unit test passes:

```
describe('myDirective test', function () {
var scope, compile, element;

beforeEach(module('myModule'));

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    element = angular.element("<my-directive></my-directive>");
    $compile(element);
    scope.$digest();
}));

it('should have a my-paragrapgh class', function () {
    expect($(element).find('p')[0]).toHaveClass('my-paragrapgh');
});

});
```

How can i successfully test a directive declared as an Attribute? I'm using Karma, Jasmine and PhantomJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have an `ng-transclude` somewhere in your template when you have the `transclude: true` so that angular will know where to inject your HTML. Try:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,

        scope: {
            data: "="
        },

        template:
            '<div ng-transclude><p class="my-paragrapgh">' +
                '<label>Hello</label>' +
            '</p></div>'
    }
});
```

**Update**

Looks like it's the `replace` option that could be causing the issue.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        scope: {
            data: "="
        },

        template:
            '<p class="my-paragrapgh">' +
                '<label>Hello</label>' +
            '</p>'
    }
});
```

With `replace: true` you're inner HTML is:

Fails

```
<label>Hello</label>
```

With `replace` undefined you have

Pass

```
<p class="my-paragrapgh"><label>Hello</label></p>
```

Comment: Should this make any difference to how i declare my element in my test: element = angular.element("<div my-directive></div>");

Comment: Added the above, with ng-translcude, the test passes, with ng-transclude, it fails

Comment: Not sure what you're after. This is what I have http://plnkr.co/edit/z9pj9unddB5zsJZZhqIW?p=preview

Comment: What im after is that is transclude spelt incorrectly, in both examples, you've advised translcude

Comment: transLCude and not transCLude

Comment: I see. Sorry about that. I guess it was just the wrapping in a <div> that was needed to make your test pass.

Comment: Updated answer. Think the issue was with the `replace` option. This option is deprecated now I think anyway so would be best to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Works with `replace` and `transclude` even if there is no `ng-trasclude`

```js
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        data: "="
      },
      template: '<p class="my-paragrapgh">' +
        '<label>Hello</label>' +
        '</p>'
    }
  });

describe('myDirective test', function() {
  var scope, compile, element;

  // Even we can introduce our Jasmine custom matcher
  beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
      toHaveCSSClass: function(util, customEqualityTesters) {
        return {
          compare: function(actual, expected) {
            debugger;
            var result = {};
            result.pass = util.equals(actual.hasClass(expected), true, customEqualityTesters);
            if (result.pass) {
              result.message = "Expected " + actual + " to not have CSS class '" + expected + "'";
            } else {
              result.message = "Expected " + actual + " to have CSS class '" + expected + "'";
            }
            return result;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });

  beforeEach(module('myModule'));


  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element("<div my-directive></div>");
    $compile(element);
    scope.$digest();
  }));

  it('has a my-paragrapgh class', function() {
    expect(element.hasClass('my-paragrapgh')).toBeTruthy();
  });
  
  it('has a my-paragrapgh class - tested by custom matcher', function() {
    expect(element).toHaveCSSClass('my-paragrapgh')
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```